# Replace keys in an array set php before insert

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the keys of quite a large array so that I only get a spcific piece of data from it. My client pastes in a set of data in a specific format into a text are which is then loaded into a series of columns in a table like so:

textarea data would be like:

```
rp1=1, rp2=3, rp4=5 etc etc
```

If I do a var dump on the post I get this:

```
array(33) { [0]=> string(2) " 8" [1]=> string(5) "RP2=7" [2]=> string(5) "RP3=9" [3]=> string(6)...
```

What I am trying to do isjust give me the figure from the key so for instance if you look at the var_dump I did I hit the first key with a string replace so I only get `8` in the array series. I am wanting to know a way to attack all of them as some of the strings contain 4 characters and some 5. so like `rp1=1 and rp10=2`.

They way I get the data from a textarea into an array is by doing this:

```
$stenData = explode(', ',  $_POST['stenData']);
```

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: So you want to cleanup stuff before insert now? I remeber the Q about cleanup data from database with same stuff `RP[0-9]+=`. You can use that preg_replace here, too.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The end result should be: `array(33) { [0]=> string(2) "8" [1]=> string(5) "3" [2]=> string(5) "4" [3]=> string(6)...`

Comment: Like `$stenData = array_map('trim',explode(', ',preg_replace('#(RP[0-9]+=)#','',$_POST['stenData'])));`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions yeah I do it seems like a much better method because there shouldnt be data in the database like that

Comment: why `[1]=> string(5) "RP2=7"` should become `[1]=> string(5) "3"` ?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions that great, in the array there are other keys like `[1]=> string(5) TS1=7"` & `[1]=> string(5) FE1=7"` can this also be applied in the preg replace too?

Comment: If you have issues with lower upper chars then do `strtoupper($_POST['stenData'])`

Comment: its not the case, I just have other keys like `TS1=, FE=7`

Comment: For more letters `'#([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*=)#'`  use `*` because of `FE=7`

Comment: How strange, it actually did them all perfectly but the last key `CNS=8` input it as exactly that still?

Comment: where does the `*` go in there?

Comment: `'#([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]*=)#'`   lookup here `2` -> `3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136968/discussion-between-phpdude-and-justonundermillions).

Comment: That has reversed the process and now all keys go in as they did but CNS just takes the value

Comment: sry, im on work. '#([A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]*=)#' works for `RP1=1, RP2=3, RP4=5, TS1=, FE=7`  like `print preg_replace('#([A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]*=)#','','RP1=1, RP2=3, RP4=5, TS1=, FE=7');`   And check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot's of ways with `array_map()`, however if you have a `var=num` syntax then parse it as a query string instead of constructing a regex:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { parse_str($v, $r); return current($r); }, $stenData);
```

Or to do it from the posted string, just replace `,` with `&` to turn it into a query string to parse:

```
parse_str(str_replace(', ', '&', $_POST['stenData']), $result);
```

Where `$result` yields something like:

```
Array
(
    [rp1] => 1
    [rp2] => 3
    [rp4] => 5
    [TS1] => 7
    [FE1] => 7
)
```

Since there's all kinds of regex going on in the comments:

```
preg_match_all('/[^=]=(\d+)/', $_POST['stenData'], $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```